# Is it possible to conditionally decode certain fields using elm-decode-pipeline

Tags: elm

I would like to decode an API response in which one of the fields value (`category`) would determine how to decode another field (`configuration`) using different sub-decoders.

I was able to accomplish such thing using `Json.Decode.mapn` functions and the `andThen` function, but I was wondering if there is any way to do such thing using `elm-decode-pipeline` as it has a nicer API and I will run out of `mapn` functions eventually.

A minimmum and somewhat trivial example would be like this:

```
type alias Machine =
    { name : String
    , specs : MachineSpecs
    }

type MachineSpecs
    = ElectricMachine ElectricSpecs
    | MechanicalMachine MechanicalSpecs
    | UnknownMachine

type alias ElectricSpecs =
    { voltage : Int
    }

type alias MechanicalSpecs =
    { gears : Int
    }
```

And some valid JSON responses would have these shapes:

```
{
  "name": "Foo electric machine",
  "category": "electric",
  "configuration": {
    "voltage": 12
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "Bar mechanical machine",
  "category": "mechanical",
  "configuration": {
    "gears": 5
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "Some machine of unknown category",
  "category": "foo"
}
```

I tried a similar approach to the one I was using with the `mapn` functions, but it doesn't work.

```
decoder : Decoder Machine
decoder =
    decode Machine
        |> required "name" string
        |> required "category" (string |> andThen catDec)


catDec : String -> Decoder MachineSpecs
catDec cat =
    case cat of
        "electric" ->
            map ElectricMachine electricDecoder

        "mechanical" ->
            map MechanicalMachine mechanicalDecoder

        _ ->
            succeed UnknownMachine


electricDecoder : Decoder ElectricSpecs
electricDecoder =
    decode ElectricSpecs
        |> requiredAt [ "configuration", "voltage" ] int


mechanicalDecoder : Decoder MechanicalSpecs
mechanicalDecoder =
    decode MechanicalSpecs
        |> requiredAt [ "configuration", "gears" ] int
```

In fact, I haven't seen any example on the web or docs using both `Json.Decode.Pipeline` and `andThen` at the same time, so I'm not sure if it's even possible.

I have set up an online example of this issue showing how it fails to decode the conditional part: https://runelm.io/c/3ut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative, you could place your `andThen` bindings before the pipeline ([ellie example](https://ellie-app.com/3tjMh4pgrvca1/2)):

```
decoder : Decoder Machine
decoder =
    field "category" string
        |> andThen catDec
        |> andThen
            (\cat ->
                decode Machine
                    |> required "name" string
                    |> hardcoded cat
            )
```

If you are running out of `mapN` numbers, consider switching to [`andMap`](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.0.0/docs/andMap.md) (or the infix version [`|:`](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.0.0/docs/infixAndMap.md)) in the [`elm-community/json-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/2.1.0/Json-Decode-Extra) package.

Answer (score 5):

[Chad Gilbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465430/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-decode-certain-fields-using-elm-decode-pipeline/41466366#41466366) just works (thanks!) and it lead me to read the `Json.Decode.Pipeline` source code to understand a bit more about how the piping was implemented and I've found an alternative solution that is a bit more concise, so I thought about sharing it here:

```
decoder : Decoder Machine
decoder =
    decode Machine
        |> required "name" string
        |> custom (field "category" string |> andThen catDec)
```